# What happens when a `subprocess.call` receives a kill signal?

Tags: python, subprocess

Does the signal continue down to the called process?

e.g., I issue a `SIGINT` to a python process that is waiting on a `subprocess.call` to finish.  `subprocess.call` is interrupted.  What happens to the child process?  What about `SIGTERM`, etc?

@zerkms points out that killing a parent process doesn't, in general, pass kill signals down to child processes.  However, it is easy to check that some such thing happens with the python `subprocess.call` function:

### Terminal 1

```
$ python3
>>> import subprocess
>>> with open("foo.py", "w") as f:
...     f.write("import time; time.sleep(6000)")
... 
29
>>> subprocess.call(["python3", "foo.py"])
```

### Terminal 2

```
$ ps aux | grep foo.py
scott 3716  ........  20:03   0:00 python3 foo.py
scott 3720  ........  20:03   0:00 grep --color=auto foo.py
```

### Terminal 1

```
<Ctrl-C>
^CTraceback (most recent call last):
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 289, in call
    return p.wait(timeout=timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 1477, in wait
    (pid, sts) = self._try_wait(0)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 1424, in _try_wait
    (pid, sts) = os.waitpid(self.pid, wait_flags)
KeyboardInterrupt
```

### Terminal 2

```
$ ps aux | grep foo.py

scott 3722  ........  20:04   0:00 grep --color=auto foo.py
```

So it seems that, at the very least, the argument of `subprocess.call` is getting killed in this scenario.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/440701/31347

Comment: this is more of a linux question than python. consider moving it to linux stack exchange  .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The linked question addresses the different scenario. There a signal is sent to the *process* (by specifying the `pid`). And indeed the child precesses survive.

In your situation, `<Ctrl-C>` is not a signal per se; it instructs the terminal driver to send `SIGINT` to *every process* in the associated process group.

Depending on how the child process was created, it may remain in the parent process group, or it may dissociate itself from it. In the latter case, `<Crtl-C>` typed in the parent's controlling terminal would have no effect on the child. Apparently, `subprocess.call` choses to keep the child attached to the original controlling terminal, so it does receive `SIGINT`.

I don't know if such behavior is documented. Generally it makes sense. Only deamons have the reason to dissociate themselves.

PS: *nix only. No idea how it works on Windows.

Comment: The same thing happens if I issue a SIGINT instead of of pressing Ctrl-C.  If I issue a SIGHUP or a SIGTERM, then foo.py is left running.